# Longitude latitude from plist to CLLocation

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have the following plist:

```
    <plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>Dodge Viper</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>Bil</string>
        <key>longitude</key>
        <real>19.027054</real>
        <key>latitude</key>
        <real>36.129471</real>
        <key>show</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>Dodge RAM</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>Truck</string>
        <key>longitude</key>
        <real>1.026062</real>
        <key>latitude</key>
        <real>46.128918</real>
        <key>show</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>Tøf tøf</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>Lastbil</string>
        <key>longitude</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>latitude</key>
        <real>56.128918</real>
        <key>show</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>Black Pearl</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>Piratskib</string>
        <key>longitude</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>latitude</key>
        <real>25.128918</real>
        <key>show</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

And I have a basic mapview controller.

What I would like is to create annotations for each item using the longitude and altitude key.

Problem is, when I try I get problems with "double" -> I don't know how to read my value from the plist as a double, I have tried converting it, but it doesn't seem to work.

My code in the map view controller is like this:

Currently there's a problem at "double latitude2 = [str objectForKey:@"latitude"];" but I included the line anyway to show my intentions.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];



    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                      @"enheder" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    for (NSString *str in array2) {

        double latitude2 = [str objectForKey:@"latitude"];


    [mapview setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];
    [mapview setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapview setScrollEnabled:YES];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region.center.latitude = latitude2;
    region.center.longitude = 9.027044;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.001f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.001f;
    [mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann.title = @"Title";
    ann.subtitle = @"Sub";
    ann.coordinate = region.center;
    [mapview addAnnotation:ann];

   }  




}
```

I am very much a novice when it comes to programming for iPhone, so it's very likely I've missed something fundamental. But any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plist han an array of dictionary not an array of strings. change your code in this way

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in array2) 
    double latitude2 = [[dict objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (NSString *str in array2) {
```

in this statement NSString replace with NSDictionary i think it will work

Comment: Yes, the plist is an array of dictionaries, not an array of strings.